# monacaでビルドしたiOSアプリのアイコンが透明アイコンになってしまいます

Tags: ios, monaca

お世話になります。 現在monacaを使用してアプリケーションの開発を行っています。

今回アプリの更新(Cordovaのバージョンアップ、一部不具合の修正）に伴い、
monacaからiOSアプリをビルドし、itunes connectにアップしたのですが、
アプリのアイコンが透明アイコン（白アイコン？）になっていて、
登録したアイコン画像が表示されません。

TestFlight経由でiphoneにインストールしてもやはり、透明アイコンのままになっています。

アイコン画像（PNG24 透明なし インタレースなし）は、前バージョンのアプリで問題なく表示されているものと、iphone6向けの画像を新たに追加しました。
念のため画像自体を確認してみたのですが、特に問題は見つけることができませんでした。

info.plistを確認したところ、以下のような記述されていたため、

---

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon.png</string>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
  <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
      <string>icon-40</string>
      <string>icon-small</string>
      <string>icon-60</string>
      <string>icon.png</string>
      <string>icon@2x</string>
      <string>icon-72</string>
      <string>icon-72@2x</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
<dict>
  <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
      <string>icon-small</string>
      <string>icon-40</string>
      <string>icon-50</string>
      <string>icon-76</string>
      <string>icon-60</string>
      <string>icon</string>
      <string>icon@2x</string>
      <string>icon-72</string>
      <string>icon-72@2x</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

---

念のため、以下のように記述しなおしました。

---

```
<key>CFBundleIconFile</key>
<string>icon.png</string>
<key>CFBundleIcons</key>
<dict>
  <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
      <string>icon-40.png</string>
      <string>icon-40@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon-small.png</string>
      <string>icon-small@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon-60.png</string>
      <string>icon-60@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon-60@3x.png</string>
      <string>icon.png</string>
      <string>icon@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon-72.png</string>
      <string>icon-72@2x.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</dict>
<key>CFBundleIcons~ipad</key>
<dict>
  <key>CFBundlePrimaryIcon</key>
  <dict>
    <key>CFBundleIconFiles</key>
    <array>
      <string>icon-small.png</string>
      <string>icon-small@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon-40.png</string>
      <string>icon-40@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon-50.png</string>
      <string>icon-50@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon-76.png</string>
      <string>icon-76@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon-60.png</string>
      <string>icon-60@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon.png</string>
      <string>icon@2x.png</string>
      <string>icon-72.png</string>
      <string>icon-72@2x.png</string>
    </array>
    <key>UIPrerenderedIcon</key>
    <false/>
  </dict>
</dict>
```

---

改めて再ビルドし、itunes connectに登録。iphone上のアプリを削除し、再インストールしたのですが、やはり透明アイコンになってしまいます。

どなたか同じような現象、お気づきの点、もしくは解決法をご存知でしたら、お教えいただけると助かります。

よろしくお願いいたします。

検証端末
　iphone5(iOS8.4)
　iphone5s(iOS8.3)

Comment: 別プロジェクトとして新規プロジェクトを作成し、全てのデータ、画像を登録しなおしビルドしたところ、表示されるようになりました。
設定等、特に違いはありませんので、monacaのクラウド側に何かキャッシュの様なものが残っていて反映が上手くできなかったのかもしれません。
お騒がせいたしました。

Comment: 自己解決した場合は自信で回答を記述し、承認してください。

Answer (score 1):

解決済みに見受けられたので回答を提示します。

> 別プロジェクトとして新規プロジェクトを作成し、
>   全てのデータ、画像を登録しなおしビルドしたところ、表示されるようになりました。